# Python: cannot train regression model in Keras

Tags: python, keras, regression

I am trying to train a DNN with Keras. The model is here defined:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2050, input_shape=(2050, 75), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(75, activation='sigmoid'))
```

The cost function is the mse. 
The idea here is training with a set of 3000 images with size 2050*75, which basically are two different features extracted from a 1025*75 image, in order to get 3000 image with size 1025*75 in the output, which are some kind of representation of the original image.

So, the input is a (3000, 2050, 75) tensor, while the output dimension is (3000, 1025, 75).

I can see why Keras gives me the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_5 to have shape (None, 2050, 75) but got array with shape (3000, 1025, 75)

There must be a way to avoid this error, maybe by redefining the DNN dimensions or layers. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

EDIT: As requested, this is the complete code.

```
X = train_set
Y = m
[n_samples, n_freq, n_time] = X.shape

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n_freq, input_shape=(n_freq, n_time), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_time, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse',metrics=['mae','accuracy'])
model.fit(np.abs(X), np.abs(Y), epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
score = model.evaluate(np.abs(X), np.abs(Y), batch_size = batch_size)
```

Comment: Are you compiling at the end?, please paste the full code of the model

Comment: You can try input_shape=(None, 2050, 75)

Comment: Where? I think I already set the input shape like (2050, 75), correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you cannot reshape the array internally using the [reshape](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) layer, because total size of new array must be unchanged. I suggest to flat the tensor, using the [flatten](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten) layer. But first, you need to reshape the y:

```
y = y.reshape(-1, 1025*75)
```

the updated model would look like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n_freq, input_shape=(n_freq, n_time), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1025*75, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse',metrics=['mae','accuracy'])
model.fit(np.abs(X), np.abs(y), epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
#score = model.evaluate(np.abs(X), np.abs(Y), batch_size = batch_size)
```

After, you can reshape you y_pred back to (-1,1015,75) shape:

```
y_pred = y_pred.reshape(-1,1015,75)
```

Comment: Hi Paddy, I tried your solution but didn't work for me, maybe I implemented it in a wrong way, i.e. I tried with and without the commented line. Consider that n_freq=2050 and n_time=75. I get the following error: **ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged**

Comment: commented line is just for you, you shouldn't change it,sorry for the missing information. 

please show the error message for the code.

Comment: Thanks for editing, te error is **ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 3000 input samples and 1500 target samples.**, which is basically my initial question: how do I go from 3000 inputs to 1500 outputs?

Comment: hah, I think I understood. Could you please provide shapes of X and y?

Comment: X -> (3000, 2050, 75), Y -> (3000, 1025, 75)

Comment: doesn't make any sense, did you reshape the y? y = y.reshape(-1, 1025*75)

Comment: Yes, sorry, after reshaping Y is (1500, 153750)

Comment: and here is the problem, the shape of y should match the X shape. I don't understand how did you get 1500, but please verify the reshape function. The new y's shape should be (3000,76875).

Comment: Yes, this is why I opened this topic: in my data, the shape of Y is twice the shape of X. That is the kind of data I have available. I may just want to stack Y over itself and solve the the problem but, while it would work in this specific case, it wouldn't be ok in general, when the shape of the two features I am using in X is different.